# How to use GOOGLEFINANCE(("CURRENCY:EURAUD")) function

Tags: google-sheets, currency, google-finance, google-finance-api

This function:

```
GOOGLEFINANCE(("CURRENCY:EURAUD"))
```

works well in Google Sheets, I have searched the web up and down for some documentation regarding this function and how it is used, the closest I've got was this

http://www.google.com/finance?q=EURAUD

Does anyone know how to use this one? or where to find documentation regarding this function?

Comment: What do you mean "How to use it"? Do you mean outside of spreadsheets? FYI the Finance API [is being shutdown on October 20](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-finance-apis/q-DbjbzQDGQ/5s8m4hra5S8J)

Comment: well, I just came across the line above, I want to create a service call that returns currency exchange from eur to aud, for example... but even in spreadsheet, that function is not documented anywhere! I think this function is not affected by the spring cleanup they announced

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you go:

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281

This is all the documentation that Google provides.

Comment: yup, they finally added it to documentation

Answer (score 23):

The specific instructions for what you are looking for are in here:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281

Remember your Google Spreadsheets Formulas might use semicolon (;) instead of comma (,) depending on Regional Settings.

Once made the replacement on some examples would look like this:

```
=GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDEUR")
=INDEX(GoogleFinance("USDEUR","price",today()-30,TODAY()),2,2)
=SPARKLINE(GoogleFinance("USDEUR","price",today()-30,today()))
```

Those 3 cells would result in something like this (the second line prints the value 30 days ago):

[image: Result of the 3 Google Spreadsheet formulas mentioned]

Answer (score 14):

Exchange rate from Euro to NOK on the first of January 2016:

```
=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:EURNOK"; "close"; DATE(2016;1;1)); 2; 2)
```

The `INDEX()` function is used because `GOOGLEFINANCE()` function actually prints out in 4 separate cells (2x2) when you call it with these arguments, with it the result will only be one cell.

Answer (score 3):

Bear in mind that the `GoogleFinance()` function isn't working 100% in the new version of Google Sheets.  For example, converting from `USD` to `GBP` using the formula `GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDGBP")` gives `0.603974` in the old version, but only 0.6 in the new one.  Looks like there's a rounding error.

Answer (score 3):

Some currency pairs have no historical data for certain days.

Compare `=GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:EURNOK", "close", DATE(2016,1,1), DATE(2016,1,12)`:

```
Date                Close
1/1/2016 23:58:00   9.6248922
1/2/2016 23:58:00   9.632922114
1/3/2016 23:58:00   9.579957264
1/4/2016 23:58:00   9.609146435
1/5/2016 23:58:00   9.573877808
1/6/2016 23:58:00   9.639368875
1/7/2016 23:58:00   9.707103569
1/8/2016 23:58:00   9.673324479
1/9/2016 23:58:00   9.702379872
1/10/2016 23:58:00  9.702721875
1/11/2016 23:58:00  9.705679083
```

and `=GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:EURRUB", "close", DATE(2016,1,1), DATE(2016,1,12)`:

```
Date                Close
1/1/2016 23:58:00   79.44402768
1/4/2016 23:58:00   79.14048175
1/5/2016 23:58:00   80.0452446
1/6/2016 23:58:00   80.3761125
1/7/2016 23:58:00   81.70830185
1/8/2016 23:58:00   81.70680013
1/11/2016 23:58:00  82.50853122
```

So, `=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:EURRUB", "close", DATE(2016,1,1)), 2, 2)` gives

```
79.44402768
```

But `=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:EURRUB", "close", DATE(2016,1,2)), 2, 2)` gives

```
#N/A
```

Therefore, when working with currency pairs that have no exchange rates for weekends/holidays, the following formula may be used for getting the exchange rate for the first following working day:

```
=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:EURRUB", "close", DATE(2016,1,2), 4), 2, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
=INDEX(GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:" & "EUR" & "USD", "price", A2), 2, 2)
```

where `A2` is the cell with a date formatted as date.

Replace "EUR" and "USD" with your currency pair.

Answer (score -1):

The syntax is:

> =GOOGLEFINANCE(ticker, [attribute], [start_date], [num_days|end_date], [interval])

[Sample usage](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281):

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG", "price", DATE(2014,1,1), DATE(2014,12,31), "DAILY")
=GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price",TODAY()-30,TODAY())
=GOOGLEFINANCE(A2,A3)
=117.80*Index(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:EURGBP", "close", DATE(2014,1,1)), 2, 2)
```

For instance if you'd like to convert the rate on specific date, here is some more advanced example:

```
=IF($C2 = "GBP", "", Index(GoogleFinance(CONCATENATE("CURRENCY:", C2, "GBP"), "close", DATE(year($A2), month($A2), day($A2)), DATE(year($A2), month($A2), day($A2)+1), "DAILY"), 2))
```

where `$A2` is your date (e.g. `01/01/2015`) and `C2` is your currency (e.g. `EUR`).

See more samples at [Docs editors Help at Google](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281).

Answer (score -2):

You have to use the equal sign in the formula box

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG", "price", DATE(2014,1,1), DATE(2014,12,31), "DAILY")
```